# Combination of querystring and terms in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query:

```
query: {
query: {
query_string: {
query: "Perspolis OR Branco",
default_field: "body"
}
},
from: 1,
size: 1
}
```

How to combine this query with an exact check for the field processed: true and age between 10 and 20?

Comment: Put example sample output ..you are expecting and Your Elastic search entity

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "Perspolis OR Branco",
            "default_field": "body"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "processed": {
              "value": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "age": {
              "gte": 10,
              "lte": 20
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 1,
  "size": 1
}
```